# Lowering Continuous Crawl time via PowerShell

Tags: search, 2013, enterprise-search, crawl

I've been reading up on new SharePoint 2013 features, and continuous crawl plus the new Content Search Web Parts will do wonders for our SharePoint project. However, by default the Continuous Crawl is set to every 15 minutes, which isn't short enough for our project.

Everything I've been reading says that you can shorten this time via PowerShell, but I haven't found any reference to what PowerShell cmdlet needs to be run or what parameters to enter to make this change. If anyone has found out how to programmatically change the Continuous Crawl time I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SetProperty("ContinuousCrawlInterval", 1)
```

Comment: This looks like it would do it, but it's been about 3 minutes after setting it and my web part hasn't caught the new item I created. Is there any kind of update I need to call via PS after I run the `SetProperty`?

On an aside, I do subscribe to your blog via RSS, but my company blocks it as malware due to misconfigured DNS. Kind of a weird place to let you know but I figure since I got you here I might as well let you know!

Comment: After another attempt of disabling/enabling Cont. Crawling and then running your script it seems as if it worked. I think the next step for us is to optimize our content searches so we can crawl several places at once in a shorter time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource cmdlet.  Here is the documentation on how to use it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607675.aspx(v=office.15).

Comment: And I believe it is the CrawlScheduleRepeatInterval parameter you need to specify.

Comment: Set EnableContinuousCrawls to true.  And then it should follow the value you set to the incremental interval.

Comment: I did a quick readthrough of that and it looks like you can only enable continious crawl there. `CrawlScheduleRepeatInverval` sounds like the right parameter, but it looks like you can only set `ScheduleType` to `Full` or `Incremental`

Comment: Looks like that isn't working. I'm running this command: 
`Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -EnableContinuousCrawls 1 -CrawlScheduleRepeatInterval 2`

Maybe I'm missing something? I apologize for not being very proficient with PowerShell so I can kind-of navigate through that TechNet article but putting it all together I'm not so great at.